# voiceChannel.play is not a function error

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
async function play(msg) {
    let mg = getMusicGuild(msg.guild.id);
    let voiceChannel = msg.guild.voiceConnection;

    if (!voiceChannel) voiceChannel = await msg.member.voiceChannel.join();

    msg.guild.me.setDeaf(true);
    let sq = mg.shiftQueue();
    mg.setDispatcher(voiceChannel.play(ytdl(sq.youtube.link,{filter:"audioonly"}),{passes:4}));
    mg.setPlayingTitle(sq.youtube.title);
    mg.getDispatcher().on('end',reason => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            let sqa = mg.queue[0];
            mg.setPlaying(false);
            if (!sqa) {
                console.log("music ended");
                voiceChannel.disconnect();
            } else {
                play(msg).catch(console.error);
            } 
        },500);
    });
    mg.setPlaying(true);
    msg.channel.send(new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(0x0ea5d3)
        .setAuthor(msg.author.username, msg.author.avatarURL)
        .setDescription(sq.youtube.description)
        .setTimestamp(new Date())
        .setTitle(sq.youtube.title)
        .setImage(sq.youtube.thumbnails.high.url)
        .setURL(sq.youtube.link)
    );
}

module.exports = {
    play: play,
    searchAddToQueue: searchAddToQueue,
    getMusicGuild: getMusicGuild
};
```

This is the code that would allow my bot to join a voice channel and play music. However, when I execute the command that allows all this to work, this error comes up:

`(node:2668) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: voiceChannel.play is not a function`

As you can tell, I'm stuck on this. What am I doing wrong in the code, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see you're doing a music bot, personally this doesn't seem efficient for music. If you want to have a more advanced music bot that works well and has many features that are hard to implement, [I recommend this.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-musicbot-addon) If you still want to make your music function with your own code I recommend you do a function similar to this:

```
function play(connection, message){
    var server = servers[message.guild.id];

    server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: 
"audioonly"}));

    server.queue.shift();

    server.dispatcher.on("end", function() {
        if(server.queue[0]) play(connection, message);
        else connection.disconnect();
    });
}
```

Keep in mind this is using `FFmpeg` and `opusscript`